# getting issue with node_modules/@types/node d.ts files

Tags: typescript, types, node-modules

I am getting an issue with follwing configuration now as below:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "1.0.4",
    "grunt-banner": "0.6.0",
    "grunt-cli": "1.3.2",
    "grunt-config-dir": "0.3.2",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "1.1.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-less": "1.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "3.4.0",
    "grunt-ts": "6.0.0-beta.22",
    "grunt-tslint": "5.0.2",
    "grunt-typedoc": "0.2.4",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "3.5.2",
    "tslint": "5.18.0",
    "typedoc": "0.9.0",
    "typescript": "2.3.4"
  }
```

and issue is as below

```
Using tsc v2.3.4

21         const captureRejectionSymbol: unique symbol;
                                                ~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/node/events.d.ts(21,46): error TS1005: '=' expected.


32         const errorMonitor: unique symbol;
                                      ~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/node/events.d.ts(32,36): error TS1005: '=' expected.


361     const REPL_MODE_SLOPPY: unique symbol;
                                       ~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/node/repl.d.ts(361,36): error TS1005: '=' expected.


367     const REPL_MODE_STRICT: unique symbol;
                                       ~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/node/repl.d.ts(367,36): error TS1005: '=' expected.


26         const custom: unique symbol;
                                ~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/node/util.d.ts(26,30): error TS1005: '=' expected.


188         const custom: unique symbol;
                                 ~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/node/util.d.ts(188,30): error TS1005: '=' expected.
```

i have removed node_modules and installed it again, but still same issue.  so what should i do for this case? i have searched multiple sites and queries, but didn't found the solution for this. So please help me in this.

Previously it was working fine. So i have no idea, why this happens?

i have also tried to update typescript to 3.7.5 also. but no luck.

Somehow i found issue with **node_modules@types\node** there is a folder version ts3.5 but when i replaced this with ts3.2 (stored at my previous location) then it works fine. So how to deal with ts version of node now?

Comment: Im getting the same issue. It seems to be related to the use of `unique`. When I remove that the errors go away. But in `util.d.ts` removing it from `promisify.custom` causes a new error `ts(1169)`.

Comment: Not the real fix. But adding the comment `//@ts-ignore` above the `util.d.ts` error works for me. My `util.d.ts` error was on line 93 (`[promisify.custom]: TCustom;`).

Comment: I installed the latest version of TypeScript as a dev dependency for my project, and the errors stopped.